# MSAL + SAML Integration Android

Tags: android, oauth, saml, azure-ad-msal

Looking to integrate SAML instead of oAuth using MSAL (Microsoft Authentication Library). I have a working android application with oauth login which was setup using the [link](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android). Now, since the application is configured with SAML for SSO in Enterprise application option in the azure portal I want the application to login using the SAML IDP but the application keeps loading the old oAuth authentication. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSAL does not support SAML. It only supports OAuth / OpenID Connect.

You need to integrate with a [SAML stack](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43).

Comment: No library available for Android? Also, is there no way I can integrate any of the microsoft library to work with SAML. PS- I have setup SAML in enterprise applications and it seems to be working fine there.

Comment: NO - MSAL will not work with SAML.

Comment: Any other library that supports SAML?