# Django app with MS Azure SAML SSO using MSAL

Tags: python, django, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I have an application created using Django that uses MSAL library to authenticate with Azure AD.
As I understand, MSAL uses OAuth and so far the authentication/authorization works great. Is there a way to implement authentication using SAML instead of OAuth. I came across `pysaml2` library but doesn't have sufficient documentation to integrate with Azure AD. Can someone please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to implement authentication using SAML instead of
> OAuth.

No it's not possible to use SAML authentication in MSAL library.MSAL does not support SAML. It only supports OAuth / OpenID Connect.

Similar kind of request also raised on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70701487/msal-saml-integration-android#:%7E:text=MSAL%20does%20not%20support%20SAML,only%20supports%20OAuth%20%2F%20OpenID%20Connect.) and [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/247209/msal-libraries-or-samples-to-get-saml2-assertions.html) as well you can check for more information

SAML is devloped by the **Security Services Technical Committee of OASIS** (Organization for the Advancement of Structured Information Standards) not by Microsoft so this might be the reason SAML is not included in MSAL Library.